# Testing the return value from an useMemo with React/Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jest-dom

I have a component that converts a person's name to two initials with a useMemo.

I simply want to test the content to be "SB" when the name is Sjaak de Boer. But the useMemo (or if I simple convert it to a return function) is slow so the test fails.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-orla-d4bvtu?file=/src/App.test.ts:0-512)

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";

interface Props {
  name?: string;
}

const ObAvatar: React.FC<Props> = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  const [nameValue, setNameValue] = useState<string>(name);

  const returnInitials = useMemo(() => {
    if ((nameValue && nameValue.length === null) || !nameValue) return "...";
    const rgx: RegExp = new RegExp(/(\p{L}{1})\p{L}+/, "gu");
    const matches: any = nameValue.matchAll(rgx); // fix any!
    let initials: Array<any> = [...matches] || [];
    initials = (
      (initials.shift()?.[1] || "") + (initials.pop()?.[1] || "")
    ).toUpperCase();
    return initials;
  }, [nameValue]);

  return (
    <span style={{ border: "solid 1px red" }} data-testid="initials">
      {returnInitials}
    </span>
  );
};

export default ObAvatar;
```

And my test is:

```
/** @jest-environment jsdom */

import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import Initials from "./Initials";

describe("Initials", () => {
  test("Should render an initials SB (Sjaak de Boer)", () => {
    render(<Initials name="Sjaak de Boer" />);
    const initialsElm: HTMLSpanElement = screen.getByTestId("initials");
    expect(initialsElm).toHaveTextContent(/SB/i);
    screen.debug();
  });
});
```

I tried using timers, but I feel I am missing some part of using the jest library.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an element that will have a delay there are a couple asynchronous functions you can use.  Use `waitFor` when you have an assertion which may not be immediately true

```
test("Should render an initials SB (Sjaak de Boer)", async () => {
    render(<App name={"Sjaak de Boer"} />);
    const initialsElm: HTMLSpanElement = screen.getByTestId("avatar-initials");
    await waitFor(() => expect(initialsElm).toHaveTextContent(/SB/i));
  });
```

or you can use `findByText` (or any of the `findBy*` functions) for elements which may not exist immediately

```
test("Should render an initials SB (Sjaak de Boer)", async () => {
    render(<App name={"Sjaak de Boer"} />);
    const initialsElm: HTMLSpanElement = await screen.findByTestId(/SB/i);
    expect(initialsElm).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks I tried using waitFor, it did not work... but! I updated the examples in codesandbox with both your suggestions and they work fine. But if I run them from vscode they fail.

Comment: If it's taking a significant amount of time, there are tweaks you can do regarding timeouts
https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/

Comment: I copied your sandbox to my local machine and all three of those tests pass.  How are you running them and what is failure you're getting?

Comment: I checked my dependencies and they are the same as I use in Codesandbox (Also passing all test). I simply run `jest components/componentName`.

The failure:
Unable to find an element with the text: SB. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

Ignored nodes: comments, script, style